# One to many relationship with NSfetchedresultscontroller

Tags: objective-c, core-data, one-to-many, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm having problems with fetching objects from a one to many relationship.
I have two entities "Featured" and "Event", the featured object contains a property of featuredEvents, this is a One-Many relationship, one "Featured" item to many "Events".

Now i need to use an NSFetchedResultsController to return the events featured in the "featuredEvents" relationship. I'm using the following code:

```
 NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedFeaturedEvents;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest;
    NSError *error = nil;

    fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"SDMFeaturedEvent"];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[]];

    fetchedFeaturedEvents = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:theManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    [fetchedFeaturedEvents performFetch:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to perform fetch.");
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
    }

    return fetchedFeaturedEvents;
```

This is great i return the featured event, but i also wish to add a predicate to only return the events in the "featuredEvents" property. So the question is how do i create the predicate?

i basically need all "Events" IN the featuredEvents property of the "Featured" object im making the fetch for, is this possible?

Comment: The featuredEvents property already gives you all the Events for the Feature.  Accessing the property automatically causes the fault to fire and loads in events - no need for a query on Event.   Not sure if I'm understanding your question.

Comment: Yes i can access them that way, but is it possible to access them via a predicate, as i would like to run other predicate methods on them?

Comment: Create a predicate that filters on the inverse relationship of feature.  For syntax, check any of a zillion examples and how-tos available via Google.

Comment: As an aside, you really should have a sort descriptor, or the FRC will have issues determining changes when the context is updated.

Comment: Hi Avi, I've tried this: [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SDMEvent IN featuredEvents"]]; But i get a crash with the following: NSInvalidArgument (LHS and RHS both keypaths) I will give it a sort descriptor once i get it working.

Comment: @SmokersCough: try this: `[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN featuredEvents", theEventYouWantToFindInFeaturedEvents]]`.

Comment: Hi jp2g, is there a way to find all "Event" objects as the whole idea is to return all the Event objects in the featureEvent relationship which is an nsset of Event objects?

Comment: If you want all Event objects you should query the Event entity and not the FeaturedEvent entity.

Comment: None of these approaches are working, i'm simply getting all Event objects returned rather than just those in the NSSet "featuredEvents"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have been having similar issues, i eventually used this approach:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects;
    NSPredicate *soldOutPredicate;
    NSPredicate *criteriaMatchPredicate;
    NSCompoundPredicate *fullPredicate;
    NSSortDescriptor *usesDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"eventDate" ascending:YES];

    fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"FeaturedEvent"];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[]];
    fetchedObjects = [theManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to perform fetch.");
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
    }

    if ([[NSSDMUserDetails sharedManager]showsCriteraMatchEvents]) {

        if ([[NSSDMUserDetails sharedManager]isUserMale]) {
            criteriaMatchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(eventAgeMaleMin <= %@) AND (eventAgeMaleMax >= %@)",[[[NSSUserDetails sharedManager]userAge]stringValue],[[[NSUserDetails sharedManager]userAge]stringValue]];
        }
        else{
            criteriaMatchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(eventAgeFemaleMin <= %@) AND (eventAgeFemaleMax >= %@)",[[[NSUserDetails sharedManager]userAge]stringValue],[[[NSUserDetails sharedManager]userAge]stringValue]];
        }

        fullPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[criteriaMatchPredicate]];

    }

    if (![[NSSDMUserDetails sharedManager]showsSoldOutEvents]) {

        if ([[NSSDMUserDetails sharedManager]isUserMale]) {
            soldOutPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eventPlacesMale == %@ || eventPlacesMale != %@",@"in stock",@"0"];
        }
        else{
            soldOutPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eventPlacesFemale == %@ || eventPlacesFemale != %@",@"in stock",@"0"];
        }

        fullPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[soldOutPredicate]];
    }

    if (soldOutPredicate && criteriaMatchPredicate) {

        fullPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[soldOutPredicate,criteriaMatchPredicate]];

    }

    if (fetchedObjects && fetchedObjects.count > 0) {

        SDMFeaturedEvent *feat = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"All featured events %@",feat.featuredEvents);
        if (fullPredicate) {
            return [[feat.featuredEvents.allObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fullPredicate]sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[usesDescriptor]];
        }
        else if (![[NSSDMUserDetails sharedManager]showsCriteraMatchEvents]){
            return [feat.featuredEvents.allObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[usesDescriptor]];
        }
        else{
            return [NSArray new];
        }

    }
    return [NSArray new];
```

The trick was to return an array of events from the featuredEvent "featuredEvents" property, you can then run the filteredArrayUsingPredicate and sortedArrayUsingDescriptor methods to sort the event objects in the array with whatever your requirements are. Granted this is not returning an NSFetchedResultsController but this works great for filtering.